# generate a random number/string or an iterator in sed 's/'

Tags: bash, sed

I adapted [Jan Goyvaerts's e-mail regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) to a bash function to be used in pipes to anonymize e-mail addresses:

```
function remove_emails { 
    sed -r "s|\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b|email.address@removed.com|gI"; 
}
```

which I'm using in a bash pipe:

```
    mysqldump \
        -uuser \
        -ppass \
        db_name \
    | remove_emails \
    | gzip -c \
    | cat \
    > tmp.sql.gz
```

works fine but now, I'd like to have different random e-mails, I'd be satisfied with:

```
email.address1@removed.com
email.address2@removed.com
```

or

```
eiyyzhupzftrvjwehbqp@removed.com
kwmbrshzmxqlrqatqpff@removed.com
```

or anything that differs and is unique

I'm quite comfortable with bash but using counters, process substitution and so fails as sed is invoked only once, so

```
sed "s,sth,$(echo $RANDOM),g"
```

and similar won't work,

Is there anything to generate random stuff or counters in sed itself?

Comment: Why do you restrict yourself to using `sed`?

Comment: no good reason, I could do that in python but speed would be an issue (I guess, correct me if I'm wrong) and I already have a working regexp for sed, also from these kinf of tools I mostly know sed.It's time to learn some perl or awk I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
<<<'Here is a random number.' sed 's/random number/& $RANDOM/;s/.*/echo "&"/e'
```

or if you prefer:

```
<<<'Here is a random number.' sed 's/random number/& $RANDOM/;s/.*/echo "&"/' | sh
```

Comment: This looks promising but it doesn't work, can you verify your code? I only get "Here is a random number ." after pasting into bash

Comment: @user35186 try setting `sh` to `bash`. You may need to alias these.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Alternatively, one could pipe through bash - [...] | bash.

Answer (score 2):

I experimented with potong's correct answer and found a way to implement an iterator which answers the other part of my question:

```
remove_emails() {
    sed -r 's|\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b|test$(( iterator++ ))@example.com|gI;s|.*|echo "&"|' | bash
}

iterator=0
test_data='some.e.mail.address.@domain.com\nsome.other@email.co.uk\nwhatever@man.biz\nsed@sed.com\n'
echo -e "before:\n${test_data}"
echo -e "after: \n${test_data}" | remove_emails
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by repeatedly invoking `sed` in a `while` loop as shown below:

```
remove_emails() { 
    while read line
    do
        sed -r "s|\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b|email.address${RANDOM}@removed.com|gI" <<< "$line"
    done
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to avoid just that. Invoked on a large database dump calling sed one or hundreds of thousand of times makes a difference but this might have to be the solution as I don't think sed has any generators.